# Error while trying to open VS code using ". code" from Mac terminal

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio, dart, terminal

This shows up after I press . code
/usr/local/bin/code: line 6: python: command not found
/usr/local/bin/code: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.